# Spring JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer threads are in Blocked state on isRunning()

Tags: spring-jms

One of our older project version is using spring JMS 4.0.2 with active mq 5.10 and we've a situation of a component sending out messages to active mq Q and other component is receiving it.

After around 400+ messages getting through, next messages just stuck and never reached to the final destination.

We tracked it to the receiving side where spring JMS piece is able to get the message but not able to invoke "onMessage" on the listener.

The thread dump of the receiving JVM shows that all those received messages threads are "BLOCKED" on 'isRunning()' which in turn waiting on lock on "lifecycleMonitor" object.

Here is the thread dump analysis:

There were 5 messages received and then those 5 threads are waiting to get lock in (isRunning()) before invoking "onMessage".

```
85 threads with same stack trace Thread 246 Thread 246 - threadId:Thread 246 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace:
- java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=502 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.activemq.FifoMessageDispatchChannel.dequeue(long) @bci=49, line=72 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dequeue(long) @bci=19, line=486 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive() @bci=17, line=573 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(javax.jms.MessageConsumer) @bci=10, line=430 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(java.lang.Object, javax.jms.Session, javax.jms.MessageConsumer, org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus) @bci=119, line=310 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(java.lang.Object, javax.jms.Session, javax.jms.MessageConsumer) @bci=94, line=263 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener() @bci=17, line=1102 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run() @bci=82, line=996 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run() @bci=4, line=62 (Compiled frame)
- de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkItem.run() @bci=112, line=100 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)

38 threads with same stack trace Thread 231 Thread 231 - threadId:Thread 231 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace:
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning() @bci=6, line=347 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run() @bci=64, line=995 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run() @bci=4, line=62 (Compiled frame)
- de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkItem.run() @bci=112, line=100 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)

5 threads with same stack trace Thread 126 Thread 126 - threadId:Thread 126 - state:BLOCKED stackTrace:
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning() @bci=6, line=347 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.scheduleNewInvokerIfAppropriate() @bci=1, line=715 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.messageReceived(java.lang.Object, javax.jms.Session) @bci=9, line=692 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(java.lang.Object, javax.jms.Session, javax.jms.MessageConsumer, org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus) @bci=222, line=317 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(java.lang.Object, javax.jms.Session, javax.jms.MessageConsumer) @bci=94, line=263 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener() @bci=17, line=1102 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run() @bci=82, line=996 (Compiled frame)
- org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run() @bci=4, line=62 (Compiled frame)
- de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkItem.run() @bci=112, line=100 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
- java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)

2 threads with same stack trace Thread 16 Thread 16 - threadId:Thread 16 - state:BLOCKED
```

Comment: I have encounter similar problem. Is this issue resolved?

Comment: yes, If I remember it right it was something to do with a workmanager lib which was commonj i suppose and a thread in the pool was getting stuck because of an exception which was not caught right. we changed a flag at the init of that lib and eventually started using one of the spring thread pool implementation as worker pool.